# Using the output of a 'grep search' as the input of a 'yum update' (Shell Script)

Tags: shell, grep, yum

I was recommended for this student job by one of my profs. I have never coded a shell script in my life. I have read some tutorials online about shell scripting, but that is it. Anyway, I have been asked to create a script that will run:

```
find-repos-of-install | grep rpmfusion
```

and given the output of that search, will run a yum update. Ex:

```
find-repos-of-install | grep rpmfusion

#that gives this output
libCg-3.1.0013-2.el6.x86_64 from repo rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
pgplot-5.2.2-34.el6.1.x86_64 from repo rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
pgplot-devel-5.2.2-34.el6.1.x86_64 from repo rpmfusion-nonfree-updates

yum update libCg pgplot pgplot-devel
```

That is what he wants the script to do. I'm not asking anyone to write the whole script for me, just try to point me in the right direction. I've done coding in Java, but that hasn't helped me at all, shell script looks like gibberish to me still. Thanks for any tips/hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options of how to call a command (yum in your case) with output of another command (grep in your case): one is to do something like:

```
$ yum update $(find-repos-of-install | grep rpmfusion)
```

Another one is to use `xargs`, something like:

```
$ find-repos-of-install | grep rpmfusion | xargs yum update
```

Comment: That is great, thank you. I ended up going with '$ find-repos-of-install | grep rpmfusion | xargs yum update -y'
Much appreciated

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help.